# Android: Sherlock Tabs and ActionBar customization

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I need some help with actionbar and tabview customization. I use Sherlock ActionBar lib and try to bind custom tab/actionbar style with Theme.Sherlock as a parent to my activity. BUt it doesn`t work, no errors but nothing is changed. What am I doing wrong?

Here are my styles:(change background color at least):

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTab</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTab</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTab" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

That`s my manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:logo="@drawable/abs__ic_go"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".FragmentTabsPager"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTHeme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I trid to use CUstomTabs and Theme.Styled(for ActionBar) styles separately but no result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
```

You shouldn't use the same name for a style like the parent you are extending. How should android know which one to choose?

A valid name would be one that includes your theme name for identification:

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TabView" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
```

Comment: That`s the good note I have corrected it but it`s still not working.

Comment: Could you please update the styles in your questions, too. Just to see the actual one

Comment: You are still using the wrong styles for the tabs in your CustomTabs style.

Comment: Guys, please, help me to fix this thing. I cannot understand how to customize styles at all, I have already tried a lot of different  ways to do it. Maybe, someone has still any solution? By Sherlock website theming is done very easy but it doesn`t work in my case.